script to copy files and rename a folder
i have a simple task of creating a script that will read the content of a CSV file containing a list of computers, and for each computer perform two operations (copy files and renaming a folder).
How do I accomplish this? the below code creates a folder containing the computer name inside the destination folder which is unwanted.
$sourceFile = "D:\priority\bin.95\*.*\"
$destinationFolder = "c:\priority\bin.95\"
$newFolderName = "c:\bin.95 bin.95.oldsh"
$csvFile = "C:\test.csv"

Import-Csv $csvFile | ForEach-Object {
    $computerName = $_.computerName # Assuming the CSV has a column 'ComputerName'
    Write-Output $computerName
  
    # Define the destination path for each computer
    $destinationPath = Join-Path $destinationFolder $computerName

    # 1. Copy the file to the computer's folder
    try {
        Copy-Item -Path $sourceFile -Destination $destinationPath -Force
        Write-Host "File copied to $destinationPath successfully." -ForegroundColor Green
    } catch {
        # Write-Host "Error copying file to $destinationPath: $_" -ForegroundColor Red
    }

    # 2. Rename the folder for each computer
    try {
       $newFolderPath = Join-Path $destinationFolder $newFolderName
      Rename-Item -Path $destinationPath -NewName $newFolderPath
      Write-Host "Folder $destinationPath renamed to $newFolderPath." -ForegroundColor Green
     } catch {
      Write-Host "Error renaming folder for $computerName: $_" -ForegroundColor Red
     }
}


Use UNC paths. That is, \\remotecomputer\.... You could also map the remote computer's drive as network drive, but that's overkill for one-shot file operation.
